# How to timeout an api in spring boot application?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, tomcat9

We have lot of APIs in our spring boot application. We want to timeout those API when they take more than 30s to return the response. I tried lot of approaches but nothing helps. is there any way to close all DB connection and throw/return error?

tried below properties

```
server.tomcat.connection-timeout=<value>
spring.mvc.async.request-timeout=<value>
```